# Pulling data from multiple excel files hosted on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, query

I have a load of excel files (consistent format, but with different content) that I would like to pull data from into one master file. All source files are saved on Sharepoint in one folder, and the destination file is also to be saved on Sharepoint.

I would like the master file to pull given fields from all files saved in the folder, without having to specify all of the file names.

I managed to get this working with Power Query for files just saved on my hard drive, but not sure the best way to achieve this same end on Sharepoint (using [this method](https://www.excel-university.com/retrieve-values-from-many-workbooks/), for reference). Really nice solution but doesn't seem to be so simple via the cloud.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Found a solution [here](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/consolidate-multiple-excel-files-in-sharepoint-using-powerquery/) that has done the trick

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on how you used that link? That link looks like it only imports SharePoint lists not Excel files? I, like your original post, am interested in pulling in data from Excel files in a SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping your SharePoint folder in file manager.  This should allow you to use the Power Query process.